# Why does HashMap.get not return a nullable type?

Tags: nullpointerexception, null, kotlin, java-collections-api, java-interop

I was a bit surprised that the following example throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val hm = HashMap<String, Int>()
    hm.put("alice", 42)
    val x = hm.get("bob")
    println(x)   // BOOM
}
```

I thought there are no `NullPointerException`s in Kotlin code?

If I annotate `x` with an optional type, the programm prints `null` instead:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val hm = HashMap<String, Int>()
    hm.put("alice", 42)
    val x: Int? = hm.get("bob")
    println(x)   // null
}
```

Have I discovered a special case, or is this a general problem with Kotlin/Java interop?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 14.1 Community Edition with Kotlin 0.11.91.1 plugin.

Comment: Read more about using and [working with nullable values in Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o/34498563#34498563)

Comment: This was a bug at the time of the question being asked, and is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your variable `hm` is of type `HashMap` and because that's a platform class its methods return [platform types](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types). Kotlin's own [`Map`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-map/index.html) and its <strike>subtrait</strike> subinterface [`MutableMap`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-mutable-map/) however return nullable types for [`get()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-map/get.html).

Change your code to

```
val hm : MutableMap<String, Int> = HashMap()
```

and it will print "null".

Comment: Why did you replace `trait` with `interface`? The docs say `trait`.

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/04/more-changes-enum-syntax-and-one-deprecation-and-more/ says "trait" will be deprecated in favor of "interface".

Comment: This code example should be:  `val hm = hashMapOf<String, Int>()` or literally create the map in the sample as read-only `val hm = mapOf("alice" to 42)`

Comment: @jayson `val hm = hashMapOf<String, Int>()` will, again, create a variable of type `HashMap`, not `MutableMap` which is the whole point.

Comment: I guess I should have made that comment more clear.  This is not CURRENTLY and issue with Kotlin, was a bug at the time, and NOW you can do what he did originally or the two examples I gave.  See full notes in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue.  Kotlin had an issue with how the JDK class was annotated telling it how to treat some methods.  Current Kotlin does not exhibit the problem you were seeing.

These both return a HashMap from Java collections, the first `hm1` being more idiomatic.

```
val hm1 = hashMapOf<String, Int>()
val hm2 = HashMap<String, Int>()
```

You can also create it as a map that already has the values if they are known ahead of time.

```
val hm3 = hashMapOf("alice" to 42)
```

or a readonly version:

```
val hm4 = mapOf("alice" to 42)
```

In all of these versions, they all print `null` when calling `get()` with an unknown value and then printing the result:

```
println(hm1.get("missing"))
println(hm2.get("missing"))
println(hm3.get("missing"))
println(hm4.get("missing"))
```

All have the same signature for `get()` since the JDK classes are annotated by the Kotlin team to know that `get()` returns a nullable value, `Int?` in this case.

Only an error in those annotations would cause a problem.  And should be [tracked as a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) if you see another one within the JDK runtime library.